# Inject dependencies makes loading heavier?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have been copying and pasting code from others controllers and some of them have dependencies which I wont use in these new controllers.

My question is, if I leave this injections, will they make my loading heavier? Or it doesnt matter? Thanks for your answers =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess in a way it makes it faster. Since I'm deleting code, it is reducing my javascript file size, which makes the browser loads the website faster.

It's not a whole lot, but any millisecond faster makes a different to the end user, right?